# Why FlxText not show me the unicode emoticons(emoji)?

Tags: text, unicode, haxe, emoji, haxeflixel

for example i have FlxText object

```
var t:FlxText=new FlxText();
```

I can show on my app the unicode symbol for example "1" , use

```
t.text="1";
t.text="\n0031";//work too
```

but i can't show the unicode symbols(from same font), like

```
t.text="";
t.text="\u1F5FB";// mount fuji
```

then i compile my project to cpp debug and can't see mount_fuji symbols. Only square frame.
What wrong with me? :)

Code tested on win7 64.

Codes was taken use FontForge programm. Any help will be good

Comment: As far as I know, HaxeFlixel doesn't support unicode emojis. Have you tried to use openfl directly?

Comment: No, i am not tried to use openfl directly. At this moment i just make the font file copy, then use FontForge clear all symbols around , and transport emoji symbols from old place to number place... 0...9. Then create new font, and display emoji use t.text="0". And this work not bad, but the way is ugly. @Gulvan

And i don't understand why the additional unicode codes not supported... japanese alphabet work done, but emoji is not work. Little later i will use korean letters, hope will work without surprise.

Comment: Have you tried with t.text="\uD83D\uDDFB";

Explanation: 1F5FB is a non-BMP character, so maybe you need to UCS-2 encode this character.